# Populating Select Box from Collection using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, collections

I'm very new to jQuery, and I'm attempting to populate a select box from a collection.  Basically, I want to take the code below, where "statuses" is the collection and move it to jQuery:

```
<widget:select property="statusCode" styleId="STATUSCODELIST" labelKey="label.status">
    <html:option value=""/>
    <c:forEach var="status" items="${applicationScope.statuses}">
        <html:option value="${status.key}"><c:out value="${status.key} - ${status.value}"/></html:option>
    </c:forEach>
</widget:select>
```

I'm trying to figure out how to get "statuses" to work something like the numbers array in this sample:

```
var numbers  = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
var list = $('#STATUSCODELIST')[0];
$.each(numbers, function(index, text) { 
    list.options[list.options.length] = new Option(index, text);
});
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a select box with an id of 'test_DDL', you could do the following:

```
var statusList = $('#test_DDL');
$.each(statuses, function (idx, status) {
    var option = "<option>" + status.key + " - " + status.value + "</option>";
    statusList.append(option);
});
```

Comment: So this is very close to what I'm looking for, it's just the reference to "statuses" that's throwing me off. In the widget:select, I can get the collection from the line <c:forEach var="status" items="${applicationScope.statuses}">, but just referencing "statuses" in the example above doesn't get that collection for me.

Comment: Actually, I see I can just do that by changing statuses to $.each("${applicationScope.statuses}", function (idx, status). The only issue i'm running into now is that i keep getting "undefined - undefined" for each option, but I'm getting the correct number of options

Comment: Forget the second comment, I'm not getting what I thought, still having trouble referencing the statuses collection

Comment: what about trying $.each(applicationScope.statuses, function ...  Assuming applicationScope is a global variable, this should work